# What are the design patterns to share same functionality in elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

What are the design patterns to share same functionality in elixir?

For example,
I have an app that "takes" a structure, "transforms" structure to different format and "pushes" it to some storage.
I have 3 structures that go thru this pipeline with 3 transformation rules and 3 storages.

the project uses `gen_stage` package and it has following structure:

```
(book)   |producer| -> |transformer| -> |indexer|
(article)|producer| -> |transformer| -> |indexer|
(post)   |producer| -> |transformer| -> |indexer|
```

Each stage is a separate module, i.e. Book.Producer, Book.Transformer, Book.Indexer.

Stages on the same vertical line doing the **same thing** but with different entities. I.e. Book.Producer taking books from database, Article.Producer taking articles from database, etc.

The "Taking from database" piece is fairly general and can be re-used across all pipelines, i.e.

```
alias Experimental.GenStage

defmodule Books.Producer do
  use GenStage

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init([]) do
    {:producer, []}
  end

  def handle_demand(demand, processed) when demand > 0 do
    events = Repo.all Book
    {:noreply, events, processed ++ events}
  end
end
```

The transformer runs a function on an entity produced from database. The indexer pushes the transformer records into another storage.

In a naive approach with a lot of duplication, I could have 9 (3 for Book, 3 for Article, 3 for Post) modules that's doing all these steps.

What options do I have to extract bits of similar functionality and share it between modules that use it.

Perhaps I can configure it via passing params at initialization stage, or just still have 9 modules, but refactor functions into another module. What is the best practice?

Comment: This is a little hard to answer without knowing what exactly is common and what is specific to the structure of the data between the 9 functions/modules. Can you include some actual code?

Comment: @Dogbert I tried to be as explicit as I could, there's not much real code, but I've added example to illustrate what is "common". Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible option for the case you mentioned is to pass the schema module you're trying to fetch from (i.e. `Book`, `Post`, etc.) as an option when starting the process (from a supervision tree, for example). You would receive those options in the call to `start_link`, and could then pass them as the second parameter when calling `GenStage.start_link`.

That would cause those options to be passed as an argument to `init` when the GenStage is starting. At this point, you can put that module in the state (along with the `processed` list in a tuple, for example) so it's passed in on every `handle_demand` call. There, you can finally use it as an argument to the call to `Repo.all`.

Modules can be passed around like any other value, and sometimes you can use that to your advantage to reuse code - this is one example where it may come in handy!

You can use a similar approach for the other parts of your flow - just figure out what varies and specify that as an option when starting the process. The transform function, for example, would be a good candidate for an option on your second step. There are a few ways you can accomplish that:

- pass in a module that implements a certain function - check out the documentation on [Behaviours](http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/typespecs-and-behaviours.html#behaviours) to get some guarantee that the function actually exists in the module;
- pass in a captured function in an existing module, for example `&BookTransformer.transform/1`;
- pass in an anonymous function: `fn data -> transform_all_the(data) end`.

Like modules, functions are first class citizens in Elixir. They can be passed around like values. This is a common code reuse pattern in functional programming languages.

Comment: how would you "pass" transform function as an option? Is it same as passing something like a module name, i.e. `BookTransformer` and making every `Transformer` respond to `.transform` function, sort of like implicit protocol. Is it recommended approach to define protocol for Transformer and then make the module you pass conform to that protocol? Thanks much!

Comment: You have some options: 
* pass a module that implements the function you want, as you mentioned (look into Behaviours to esure it _does_ implement the function)
* pass a "captured" function, i.e. `&BookTransformer.transform/1` 
* pass an anonymous function: `fn data -> do_something_with(data) end`

Those are all valid values that can be passed around :)

Comment: Thiago, please update original answer with this extra info and I'll mark it as accepted, thanks much for ideas!

Comment: Done. I included a link to the Behaviours page in the documentation if you choose to go that way. Hope I have helped!